# Is there any way to use floats in Solidity? I need them for a small contract that I'm writing. If floats aren't possible, what can I use instead?

Tags: solidity

I need to do some float based arithmetic but I can't find any support for such basic functionality in Solidity. Is there any way around this?

I tried searching all over the place for ways to do this. Would really appreciate some pointers. Sorry also that I can't really share code. Would really appreciate help on this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;

contract test {
  //float result;
  uint8 a = 10;
  uint8 b = 4;


  function divide() public returns(float) { // I know this isn't possible 
    result = a / b;
  }
}
```

I get a compilation error. I looked for a long time for how to do something like this. Maybe someone here knows something about this

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your use case it is hard for me to help more than this:

You can simply multiply each value by 100 then do the division and have the consumer of the value do the conversion back.  Pseudo code below:

```
contract test {
  //float result;
  uint8 a = 10;
  uint8 b = 4;


  function divide() public returns(integer) {
    result = (a * 100) / (b * 100);
  }
}
```